# How to send a value from a search box to a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box and I have no clue how to append the string that the user searches to url after a user clicks search.

How would this work?

I have a reference code but I want to know how to append the value that a user searches:

```
onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?q1=Asustablet&x=70&y=14=siys';return false"
```

Here is my [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr6N/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yu can't use jquery  inline. you can use its events like this:

```
$('#search-button-4').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')+'?q1=Asustablet&x=70&y=14=siys'; 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr6N/3/)

Comment: That's perfect but I don't want it to search the site. I want it to just append itself to the url without actually searching for it. Is that possible?

Comment: in jsfiddle doesn't work redirect, try inside your site, or alert the url like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr6N/5/ @user2680614

Comment: Yes I've tried it in my site. Do you see the string above (?q1=Asustablet&x=70&y=14=siys)? It appends to the url instead of taking me to the full url (http://fairdash.com/?q1=Asustablet&x=70&y=14=siys)

Comment: Basically, I just want the variables type in the search bar to attach itself to the next page after it loads; like the code above does already.

Comment: try to add http:// like this: window.location.href = 'http://' + $(this).attr('href')+'?q1=Asustablet&x=70&y=14=siys'; @user2680614

Comment: I've added that and nothing. Is there a way we can turn the search value into a string that attaches after page 2 is done loading?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using PHP as it will be much easier,
Add this inside PHP tags and set the variable for $user_search_input

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."?search=".$user_search_input);
```

I'm sorry if you needed a Javascript version but if not I highly suggest PHP for it has a lot of functionality being very powerful and has a lot of potential.

Comment: I have no experience in PHP.